# Can browse localhost but can not ping it on a Mac

Tags: localhost, ping, macos-sierra

Recently, I bought a new Mac mini and installed the Apache and MySQL server with Xampp (v. 7.19). I want to set up a local server in my room. I used Xampp on the Macbook and it worked without any problem. I can ping and access the websites saved in the Macbook from other devices.
On the Mac mini, I could access the localhost in the browser, however, I could not ping localhost nor 127.0.0.1 in the Terminal (Request timeout). Therefore, the other machine couldn't access it through the network.
Among the related posts, many people mentioned that most time the problem was caused by the setting of Firewall. But in my case, it seems not the reason. In the Firewall option, the "Stealth mode" was not enabled. I also tried to turn off the Firewall, but it didn't help to solve it.

Could you provide me some suggestions to check and fix the problem?

Thank you very much.

Tiger

Answer (score 0):

please try  [localhost:8080 port](//localhosts.mobi/8080) number  your wammp server must be installed diffrent port number. http://localhost:8080/

Comment: please try 8080 port number! your wammp server must be installed diffrent port number. http://localhost:8080/

Comment: [link](http://example.com/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884)